# Deploying Simple Socket.io Flask App To Google App Engine: Still Unsolved

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, socket.io

im trying to deploy a small flask app that uses socket.io to host a small live chat website

I was able to successfully run it locally (127.0.0.1)

then I went to deploy it to the google app engine with the following files:

main.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'vnkdjnfjknfl1232#'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')

def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python

network:
  session_affinity: true
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.12.2
flask-socketio
eventlet==0.17.4
gunicorn==18.0.0
```

alongside a completely functioning HTML page containing the following script:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="User Name"/>
      <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Messages"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

      socket.on( 'connect', function() {
        socket.emit( 'my event', {
          data: 'User Connected'
        } )
        var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault()
          let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val()
          let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
          socket.emit( 'my event', {
            user_name : user_name,
            message : user_input
          } )
          $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
        } )
      } )
      socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
        console.log( msg )
        if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
          $( 'h3' ).remove()
          $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+ "\n" + '</div>' )
        }
      })
    </script>
```

here's the link so you can see what's happening: https://flask-chat-for-mckenna.wl.r.appspot.com/

**Update**

> I don't get a 405 anymore after changing my endpoint from HTTP to HTTPS (thank you Simeon Nedkov!)
> It seems that it's having trouble connecting? it takes longer than usual to stop buffering
> [image: console from google]

*all code is up to date*

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is informing you that the browser refused to access an insecure endpoint.

This happens when a page served over `https://...` tries to access a resource that lives at `http://...`.

Luckily, in this case you're in control of the unsecure endpoint and can fix the problem by changing

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
```

Comment: that fixed the 405 response, thank you! I'm still having some trouble with it so I'm going to update my question, but you've helped a lot.